# Why *not* "inherit"/extend from Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It is well-known that declaring objects with JSON notation makes them "inherit" from (or, more precisely, to be built like) the base Object:

`myobj={a:1, b:2};`

which is *nearly* equivalent to `myobj = Object.create(Object); myobj.a=1; myobj.b=2;`

and than:

> Object.getPrototypeOf(myobj)

prints the following:

```
Object
    __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
    __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
    __lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
    __lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
    constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
    hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
    isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
    propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
    toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
    toString: function toString() { [native code] }
    valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
```

However, one can call `Object.create()` while supplying `null` as an argument:

```
myobj2 = Object.create(null);
```

In this case empty prototype will be returned:

```
Object
    No Properties
```

And here goes the question: in which cases and why should I care to break the prototype chain to the original `Object`? Where it can be useful?

**Update:** as already corrected down below, I mean `Object.create(Object.prototype)` rather than `Object.create(Object)` that would return `Function` object (indeed `Object()` is a constructor function for `Object` prototypees).

Comment: Nit pick: It is not *JSON notation* (which would be *JavaScript Object Notation notation* btw), but simply an *object literal*. But besides that it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
myobj = Object.create(Object);
```

...I think you mean this is the equivalent:

```
myobj = Object.create(Object.prototype);
```

...because:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( {a:1, b:2} ) === Object.prototype;  // true
```

---

As to why to use `null` early, if your object has no need for any of the properties of `Object.prototype`, ending the chain early would technically (though marginally) speed up property lookups when a property ***does not exist*** on the object in question.

*Note that I say "early" because the chain always ends with `null`.*

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.prototype );  // null
```

---

```
             obj ----------> proto -------> Object.proto -----> null
         +---------+      +---------+      +-------------+     
         |         |      |         |      |             |
         |  foo:1  |      |  bar:1  |      | toString:fn |      null
         |         |      |         |      |             |
         +---------+      +---------+      +-------------+ 
              ^                ^                  ^               X
              |                |                  |               |
obj.foo ------+                |                  |               |
              ^                |                  |               |
obj.bar-------+----------------+                  |               |
              ^                ^                  |               |
obj.toString--+----------------+------------------+               |
              ^                ^                  ^               |
obj.baz-------+----------------+------------------+---------------+

   ^---property lookups
```

Notice that the `baz` property does not exist anywhere in the prototype chain.

Because of this, it needs to search each object in sequence until it finally reaches `null` before it realizes that `baz` doesn't exist anywhere.

If you eliminate the `Object.prototype` from the chain, it will get to `null` a little quicker.

Comment: So, IF I've got you right, the only "obvious" reason for a `null` prototype is micro-tweaked performance issues / feature completeness?

Comment: @BreakPhreak: Yes. The prototype chain always ends in `null`. The sooner you get to `null`, the sooner the chain ends, stopping the property lookup. Anything else would (in my estimation) be an edge case, like if someone for some reason wanted `my_obj instanceof Object; // false`

Comment: Its not only performance. Sometimes you just don't want those properties there at all (for example when implementing a hash table you don't want any extraneous keys)

Comment: @missingno: can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: When you want to use an object to store key-value pairs having fake keys like hasOwnProperty and can be undesireable. Kinda theoretical though since Object.create is not that widespread yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858621/interiting-from-null-object-does-not-seem-to-affect-performance - tried to mess/profile a bit with performance tuning and prototypes. Just as a side node (and maybe someone will have to say anything regarding the results I've measured).

Comment: @BreakPhreak: Any (marginal) performance gained by shortening the prototype chain with `null` would only be experienced when trying to access properties that *do not exist* anywhere in the chain. In your examples , you're accessing properties that *do exist*. Once that property is found, the rest of the prototype chain is ignored, whether it is `null`, or is a chain of 50 prototype objects. So if you use `null`, the only reason I could imagine would be that you want that tiny performance benefit, and you don't want what `Object.prototype` provides.