# "Interiting" from null object does not seem to affect performance

Tags: javascript, profiling

I've [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676537/why-not-inherit-extend-from-object-in-javascript) to understand better why should one (or shouldn't) inherit from Object (`var o = Object.create(null);`). If I've got the answer right, performance reasons seemed to be the main viable reason to "inherit" from null.

So, I wanted to check it (utilizing small, handy and cute profiler called [JSLitmus](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="JSLitmus.js"></script>
    <script>
    JSLitmus.test('Prototypeless test', function() {
        var o1 = Object.create(null);
        o1.foo = "bar";
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
          o1.foo;
        };
    });

    JSLitmus.test('Prototypeful test', function() {
        var o2 = {};
        o2.foo = "bar";
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
          o2.foo;
        };
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When executed, I've got the same (controversial) results. Does it mean that there is no performance penalty when inheriting from `Object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reconsidered my own code and slightly modified the code to make the `foo` field lookup to propagate through the "inheritance" chain:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="JSLitmus.js"></script>
    <script>
    var o1 = Object.create(null);
    o1.foo = "bar";

    var o2 = Object.create(o1);

    var count;

    JSLitmus.test('Prototypeless test', function() {
        while(--count) {
          o1.foo;
        };
    });

    JSLitmus.test('Prototypeful test', function() {
        while(--count) {
          o2.foo;
        };
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In this way, I've got 10% better results when accessing the `o1` property.

Comment: Of course you do. Because property lookup is not free. However modern JIT compilers can reduces that cost to near zero so its a micro optimisation.

Comment: Than it's kinda no reason to "inherit" from null, huh. Some redundant language feature. And the end of story, I guess :)

Comment: correct there is _little_ point, however you can imagine people complaining that `Object.prototype` is _always_ in their prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no performance penalty.

Why would there be? It doesn't have the check `[[Prototype]]` because `foo` is an own property of `o`.

The reason you want to inherit from `null` is to build your own prototype chains. It's just allowing you control.

In general you would want to inherit from `Object.prototype` because the methods on it are useful and almost all code kind of "assumes" every thing inherits from it.

However you can just create your own chain with special logic

```
var newObject = Object.make(null,{
  toString: function  () { return "foobar"; },
  valueOf: function () { return 42;  }
});
```

For some value of [`Object.make`](https://github.com/raynos/pd#pd.make)

And then just create instances of that

```
var o = Object.create(newObject);
console.log(o + 3);
console.log("foo" + o);
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WG5Sq/4/).

If you really want to have fine grained custom control of `.valueOf` and other methods then really it would make sense not to inherit from `Object.prototype` for debugging purposes (i.e. not accidentally using Object.prototype methods instead of your own).

Other then that I don't think there is a real use-case for it. It might be marginally faster, or take up marginally less memory.

Comment: Just reconsidered the primary code snippet and listed above my own answer. Is my logic consistent and the point is (paranoically :) "proven", please?